# Drools 6.2.0.Final: EntityManager is closed

Tags: spring, jpa, drools, jta

Migrating to Drools 6.2.0.Final from v5, I am having issues with JPA persistence.
Environment: JTA transactions managed by Spring.

Environment configuration:

```
// transaction manager is a Spring JTATransactionManager. This seems to activate the KieSpringTransactionManager/KieSpringJpaManager
env.set(EnvironmentName.TRANSACTION_MANAGER, transactionManager);
env.set(EnvironmentName.ENTITY_MANAGER_FACTORY, entityManagerFactory);
```

It seems that the TriggerUpdateTransactionSynchronization.beforeCompletion() method accesses the EntityManager to retrieve objects for the session.
However, this entity manager has already been closed by Spring in it's own beforeCompletion transaction synchronization, hence the exception.

Is that normal behavior? Am I doing something wrong?

Any help appreciated.

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: EntityManager is closed
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerImpl.getSession(EntityManagerImpl.java:95) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.contains(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:958) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:366) ~[spring-orm-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at $Proxy108.contains(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.drools.persistence.TriggerUpdateTransactionSynchronization.beforeCompletion(TriggerUpdateTransactionSynchronization.java:43) ~[drools-persistence-jpa-6.2.0.Final.jar:6.2.0.Final]
    at org.kie.spring.persistence.SpringTransactionSynchronizationAdapter.beforeCompletion(SpringTransactionSynchronizationAdapter.java:54) ~[kie-spring-6.2.0.Final.jar:6.2.0.Final]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCompletion(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:106) ~[spring-tx-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCompletion(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:938) [spring-tx-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:835) [spring-tx-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:823) [spring-tx-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:493) [spring-tx-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:264) [spring-tx-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94) [spring-tx-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80) [spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at config.aspect.FacadeExceptionWrapping.wrapRuntimeIntoGenericExceptions(FacadeExceptionWrapping.java:48) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor113.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_26]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621) [spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610) [spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65) [spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:91) [spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204) [spring-aop-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
    at $Proxy179.completeReadOnlyTask(Unknown Source) [$Proxy179.class:na]
    at com.joss.system.webapp.controller.AbstractEditorController.completeReadOnlyTask(AbstractEditorController.java:283) [classes/:na]
```